# How to delete GCS folder from Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

Using https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/tree/master/storage or https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client, I can delete a files by specifying its file name, but there seems not to be ways to delete folders.

Is there any ways to delete folders ?

I found this([Google Cloud Storage: How to Delete a folder (recursively) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789714/google-cloud-storage-how-to-delete-a-folder-recursively-in-python)) in stackvoerflow, but this answer simply deletes all the files in the folder, not deleting the folder itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code mentioned in the [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789903/8456296) you referred works, the prefix should look like this:

```js
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('my-bucket')

blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='my-folder/')

for blob in blobs:
    blob.delete()
```

Answer (score 9):

```
from google.cloud import storage
    
def delete_storage_folder(bucket_name, folder):
    """
    This function deletes from GCP Storage

    :param bucket_name: The bucket name in which the file is to be placed
    :param folder: Folder name to be deleted
    :return: returns nothing
    """
    cloud_storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = cloud_storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    try:
        bucket.delete_blobs(blobs=list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder)))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e.message))
```