# deleting a folder inside gcp bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, bucket, google-cloud-storage

I am having a temporary folder which I want to delete in gcp bucket I want to delete it with all its content, what I thought of is I can pass the path of this temp folder as a prefix and list all blobs inside it and delete every blob, but I had doubts that it would delete the blobs inside it without deleting the folder itself, is it right? The aim goal is to find  `folder1/` empty without the temp folder but, when I tried I found un expected behavior I found the folder that contains this temp folder is deleted !!
for example if we have `folder1/tempfolder/file1.csv` and `folder1/tempfolder/file2.csv` I found that folder1 is deleted after applying my changes, here are the changes applied:

```
delete_folder_on_uri(storage_client,"gs://bucketname/folder1/tempfolder/")
def delete_folder_on_uri(storage_client, folder_gcs_uri):
    bucket_uri = BucketUri(folder_gcs_uri)
    delete_folder(storage_client, bucket_uri.name, bucket_uri.key)

def delete_folder(storage_client, bucket_name, folder):
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder)

    for blob in blobs:
        
        blob.delete()
```

PS: `BucketUri` is a class in which `bucket_uri.name` retrieves the bucket name and `bucket_uri.key` retrieves the path which is `folder1/tempfolder/`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `folder` in the GCS at all. The "folder" - is just a human friendly representation of an object's (or file's) prefix. So the full path looks like `gs://bucket-name/prefix/another-prefix/object-name`. As there are [no folders](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders#:%7E:text=Cloud%20Storage%20operates%20with%20a%20flat%20namespace%2C%20which%20means%20that%20folders%20don%27t%20actually%20exist%20within%20Cloud%20Storage) (ontologically) - thus - there is nothing to delete.

Thus you might need to delete all objects (files) which start with a some prefix in a given bucket.

I think you are doing everything correctly.

Here is an old example (similar to your code) - [How to delete GCS folder from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165246/how-to-delete-gcs-folder-from-python)

And here is an API description - [Blobs / Objects](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html) - you might like to check the `delete` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yea that's why I expected that I will find the objects deleted only and the containers (the prefix exist) but in my case I don't find it, it deletes the object with the folder (prefix) contains it. that folder1/tempfolder/ doesn't exist anymore not only the files in it.