# PHP - How can I delete a GCP bucket folder and all files/folders within it?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to delete a folder in a GCP bucket using the gs storage PHP library.

The folder structure is like so

```
-Folder1
--Folder1.1
---File
---File
--Folder1.2
---File

-Folder2
--Folder2.1
---File
---File
--Folder2.3
---File
```

Hopefully, that makes sense. If not, I basically just need to delete a folder and all files and folders within it.

When I do

```
$storage->bucket($_ENV['bucket_name'])->object('folder1')->delete();
```

I just get a 404 "No such object" error. I can't see any additional options to use in the library to delete a folder and its contents.

Comment: How are you trying to delete objects. I believe via Service Accounts ? check permissions on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly delete the folder just only using the `$object->delete()` function. You need to list all the object inside the folder with the use of [`prefix`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.39.2/storage/storageclient?method=buckets) in bucket to locate specific location of your folder.. Then, delete it one by one because the API only supports deleting a single object at a time. It means, there is no API call to delete multiple objects using wildcards or the like clause.

To delete all files including the folder use the sample code below, inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789903/8753991) :

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

function delete_Folder($bucketName)
{

    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $objects = $bucket->objects([
        'prefix' => 'foldername/'
    ]);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        $object->delete();
        printf('Deleted object: %s' . PHP_EOL, $object->name());
    }
}

delete_Folder("mybucket");
```